# Stored Procedure With Bit Parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

One of the parameters is of Bit datatype. Though the values in DB table are only 0's and 1's, when sending the parameter from interface, it can also be a null. The foll. query gives 0 rows. I suspect the problem could be with this bit parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GETDATA (@username  VARCHAR(50),
                         @profileid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                         @status    BIT)
AS
  BEGIN
      IF @username = ''
        SET @username = NULL
      ELSE
        SET @username = '%' + @username + '%'

      IF @profileid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        SET @profileid = NULL

      SELECT u.*
      FROM   tbluser u
      WHERE  u.deleted = 0
             AND ( u.username like @username
                    OR u.username IS NULL )
             AND ( u.profileid = @profileid
                    OR u.profileid IS NULL )
             AND ( u.status = @status
                    OR ( @status IS NULL
                         AND u.status IS NULL ) )
  END

--execute GetData null,null,null
```

Expected Output

```
UserId EmpId Username profileid status
--------------------------------------
 1      101   user1     10       1
```

Comment: Looks OK. Whether it works correctly depends on the desired semantics that you haven't told us. Please show a row of data that you are expecting to be returned that isn't.

Comment: @Martin, I have updated my question with the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for the `status` column is different from the other two and will always fail when you pass in `NULL` (because you say the values in the database are always `0` and `1`).

Do you really want this logic?

```
  WHERE  u.deleted = 0
         AND ( u.username = @username OR @username IS NULL )
         AND ( u.profileid = @profileid OR @profileid IS NULL )
         AND ( u.status = @status OR @status IS NULL )
```

This will treat `NULL` input parameters as not doing any filtering on the column.

Comment: Yes. This is what I want, cos this parameter is coming from a dropdown, that has 3 items - one with value 0, another 1 and the last - no value at all. And hence the null value.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with your procedure.  The first one is this combination:

```
IF @username = ''
    SET @username = NULL
ELSE
    SET @username = '%' + @username + '%'
```

followed by

```
 u.username = @username
```

If a null value is sent, this code will execute:

```
SET @username = '%' + @username + '%'
```

That will make @username = null, and the query will crash because you can't have

```
where somefield = null
```

You have to have

```
where somefield is null
```

There is a similar problem with passing an empty string.  Now, suppose a value of 'fred' is passed as the username.  Once again, this executes:

```
SET @username = '%' + @username + '%'
```

and this:

```
 u.username = @username
```

becomes

```
 u.username = '%fred%'
```

You probably wanted the word like instead of an equal sign there.

For the @status variable, if your db does not have null values, don't look for any.  If you get one passed to the proc, you probably want to use dynamic sql, or a case construct.  Something like this should work.

```
and u.status = case when @status is not null then @status
else u.status end
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have procedures working fine with the same approach. Its just that this one has bit as a parameter.